# Where is the classes! macro in Yew

Tags: rust, webassembly, yew

I am using [Yew](https://yew.rs/docs/en/) for one of my experiment project.

What is module to import for the `classes!` macro?

```
html! {
    <div
        class=classes!(
            "my-container-class",
            fill.as_some("my-fill-class"),
            class.clone(),
        )
    >
        { children.clone() }
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can't find the `classes!` macro, is because it isn't part of the latest 0.17.4 release.

If you check out the [Yew Docs for classes](https://yew.rs/docs/en/concepts/html/elements#classes), then you'll notice that they use `vec!` in the examples. Similarly, if you check out [the commit](https://github.com/yewstack/yew/tree/v0.17) that was part of the 0.17.4 release, then you'll similarly see no usage of the `classes!` macro anywhere.

If you browse the repository in its current state, then there's plenty uses of the `classes!` macro. You can even check the *next version* of the [Yew Docs for classes](https://yew.rs/docs/en/next/concepts/html/classes), which does feature the `classes!` macro.

---

If you don't want to wait until the next release of `yew`. Then you can update your dependency to use the repository instead.

```
[dependencies]
yew = { git = "https://github.com/yewstack/yew" }
```

Be warned though, any commit could potentially break your build. In that case to feel a bit less uneasy, you can target a specific commit.

```
[dependencies]
yew = { git = "https://github.com/yewstack/yew", rev = "60fed58" }
```

---

Then after that, importing `classes!` is just:

```rust
use yew::{classes, html};
```